# Password verify function in codeigniter for login

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi all I have this issue when I validate log in in `codeigniter` that seems it does not check the required password in my database.The required password in my database is hash using this

```
$password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

How can i used password_verify function in my model code?

Here is my model code:

```
public function login($data) {

    $condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' AND " . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) 
    {
        return true;
    } else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function login_user() 
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean','required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

          $this->load->view('login_view');
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname')
        );
        $result = $this->login_database->login($data);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
                    // Add user data in session
            $this->session->set_userdata('username', $data['username']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('firstname', $data['firstname']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('lastname', $data['lastname']);

            //redirect to dashboard
            $this->load->view('include/sidenavbar');
            $this->load->view('include/topnavbar');
            $this->load->view('dashboard');
        } else {


             $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Login is invalid. Please try again!');
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me how to do this..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the actual issue you are facing?

Comment: my password in db is in hash format..if it is in hash format its not logged in properly..if i gave normal text its working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use password_verify() to know if you're password is valid.

Try this model function:

```
public function login($data) {
    $this->db->select('password');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $data['username']);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $record = $query->row_array();
        return password_verify($data['password'], $record['password']);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

after returning data from model you can check for correct password using `password_verify`()

```
$data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
        'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname')
    );

$result = $this->login_database->login($data);
/*$result should return a single user data (in array form here)*/
if (! empty($result)) 
{
    if (password_verify($data['password'], $result['password'])) 
    {
       $this->session->set_userdata('username', $data['username']);
       $this->session->set_userdata('firstname', $data['firstname']);
       $this->session->set_userdata('lastname', $data['lastname']);

       //redirect to dashboard
       redirect('dashboard'); /*use redirect()*/
      //$this->load->view('include/sidenavbar');
      //$this->load->view('include/topnavbar');
      //$this->load->view('dashboard');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Password is invalid. Please try again!');
        $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
    }      

} 
else 
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Login is invalid. Please try again!');
    $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
}
```

Your model should be like this :

```
public function login($data) 
{
    $this->db->where('username', $data['username']);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $user = $query->row_array();
        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Update** : dashboard method

```
public function dashboard()
{
    /*$data['title'] = 'my title';
    you can pass data to the view like this 
    $this->load->view('dashboard',$data);
    */
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('dashboard');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: @pradeep hi pradeep i have one doubt